# How do I get a site that uses Full Trust to work on a host that uses Medium Trust?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, security

I am trying to publish my site on a host that uses Medium trust, I can't do this because it throws a System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission-error.

Which it doesn't when I use Full trust.

How do I turn off Reflection? As far as I understand, this is the only solution?

Comment: Is it .NET 4.5? Because "ASP.NET applications running on .NET 4.5 are supported only in Full Trust." https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/795612/mvc5-template-project-cannot-deploy-to-hosting-service

Comment: Do you have any tip in my case to solve this? Should I build an application in version pre 4.5? Is there nothing else I can do?